# What is the mathematical equation to calculate the RSS or RSSI at a receiver, receiving a signal via single reflection ?

Tags: signal, wireless, reflection

I have received certain answers on how to use your laptop or WARP or WLAN NIC to get the RSS or the RSSI, but what I'm interested in is the mathematics that is involved in calculating the RSS. Consider a situation as below

L_1, L_2, angle, and the reflection and transmission coefficients are all known, what else should i know so that a mathematical equation can be written for calculating the RSS.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to calculate it as a direct signal without a reflection?

Comment: Check here for ideas as well.  -  https://www.google.com/search?q=propagation+path+calculations+wifi

Comment: There are many things that go into calculating the received power from a transmitter.  Go on line and do a search for "Link budget" for some good references,

Answer (score 1):

The reflecting surface will cause a loss of received signal due to the angle of incidence and refraction from, and absorption within, the reflector.

Your problem sheet states that the reflection coefficient is known so you apply the Friis equation and treat the reflection as a loss based upon the reflection coefficient.

If you know the dielectric properties of the transmission mediums, you could also calculate the multipath effect of the signals.